# Virtualbox VM can't connect to internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 machine (splits its time between Ethernet connection and Wireless connection) and want to develop in a Linux environment, so I installed VirtualBox, and made a Linux Mint VM.

However, the VM cannot connect to the Internet at all. Even a simple ping to Google times out. I've tried most everything I've come across (bridged connection, host-only adapter) without any change at all. It seems like NAT is the 'correct' option - I'd want the virtual machine to jump through my machine's Internet connection - but, as you can see, no dice with these settings.

Is there a particular thing I'm probably doing wrong here? Could the firewalls and/or the proxy server be keeping out my VM from accessing the Internet, and if so, how would I verify that?

[image: ...]

Comment: If this is on your network at work, it is possible that the machine is being blocked. You may have to work with your administrator to get the device whitelisted. Most likely you will have to give them the MAC address of the VM

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like NAT is the 'correct' option - I'd want the virtual machine to jump through my machine's Internet connection[.]

The VM's internet connection will always be made through the hosts. And for setup and testing, `Bridged Adapter` is likely the better option.

> Is there a particular thing I'm probably doing wrong here?

It's difficult to say. There are port forwarding settings under the advanced `NAT` options. However, it the more likely culprits might be:

- An incorrectly configured VM (i.e. the OS itself).
- Your hosts firewall.
- The network your attached to blocking communication.

Or even some combination of all three.

> Could the firewalls and/or the proxy server be keeping out my VM from accessing the Internet, and if so, how would I verify that?

Possibly.

You may wish to try using the host/VM on another network. If possible, you could also potentially disable any firewall (Windows or otherwise) or proxy and try testing the VM connection again.